# mark first time a value appears in a table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with referrers:

```
`date       | referrer             | new?
2015-01-01  example.com/link.php  
2015-01-02  example.com/link.php
2015-01-03  example.com/link.php
2015-01-01  someotherlink.com
2015-01-03  someotherlink.com`
```

Now I'd like to set the field new to true if it is the first occurence of a referrer.

```
`date       | referrer             | new?
2015-01-01  example.com/link.php    true
2015-01-02  example.com/link.php
2015-01-03  example.com/link.php
2015-01-01  someotherlink.com       true
2015-01-03  someotherlink.com`
```

The table gets updated daily and the first time I have a larger timeframe for which I'd like to mark the first occurence.

Any ideas? For the daily update I could just check whether a referrer already exists before entering it in the table, but I think there is one SQL statement which can do it for all values in the table and which I only run once daily after updating the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables for this.  In a `select` this looks like:

```
select referrer, date,
       (if(@r = referrer, 0,
           if(@r := referrer, 1, 1)
       ) as newflag
from referrers r cross join
     (select @r := '')
order by referrer, date;
```

If you want the column to be updated permanently, you can do it as:

```
update referrers r left join
       (select referrer, min(date) as mindate
        from referrers
        group by referrer
       ) rr
       on rr.referrer = r.referrer and r.date = rr.mindate
    r.isnew = (rr.referrer is not null);
```

This assumes that the date is unique for each referrer -- or at least the minimum date is.